# Finding the intercept of an x-axis - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined the following function to determine where a line intercepts the x axis of a straight line graph. It should return `(Float, Bool)` where `Float` is the location the line crosses the x axis and `Bool` is `True` if it meets the x axis at > 0 and `False` if it does not.

```
x-intercept :: (Int, Int) -> (Float, Bool)
x-intercept (x,y)
  | x>0 = (x, True)
  | otherwise = (x, False)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Syntax error in declaration
>   (unexpected `';'`, possibly due to bad
>   layout)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

`-` is illegal in function names in Haskell (as opposed to Lisp dialects). GHC 7.0.3 generates a better error message though:

```
Invalid type signature: x - intercept :: (Int, Int)
                                         -> (Float, Bool)
Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

Fix: rename your function to `xIntercept`. Then, you will face another problem: you use the variable `x` both as `Int` and as `Float`. This is illegal as well, you'll have to use `fromIntegral` to fix it.

Answer (score 5):

As others have already answered your question, I would suggest a design change in the function definition.

```
x-intercept :: (Int, Int) -> Maybe Float
```

This way the function will return a Just float value in case the line intercept otherwise it will return Nothing

Comment: Thanks Ankur - yes I agree that this would be a more suitable definition.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell is not Lisp. You cannot have a hyphen in your expression-binding-name.

Answer (score 2):

- x-intercept is `x - intercept`
- x is Int but you should return Float in tuple (eg: `fromIntegral`)